# What does In[num] mean in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know that `In[*]` means the kernel is running

[image]

But what does `In[93]` mean?

[image]

Does that mean the total number of seconds to execute the cell or is that the line number?

Comment: It's the *n*-th cell to be run. Restart the kernel if you want to see it start from the  beginning. Each time you run a cell, the count will increment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's effectively a line number.

`In` is an array of all of the inputs you have entered during a session, and `Out` is a dictionary of the results from the corresponding inputs. You can use these to reference previous inputs and results; for example:

```
 In[1]:  0x7b
Out[1]:  123

 In[2]:  0x1c8
Out[2]:  456

 In[3]:  Out[1] + Out[2]
Out[3]:  579

 In[4]:  In
Out[4]:  ['', '0x7b', '0x1c8', 'Out[1] + Out[2]', 'In']

 In[5]:  Out
Out[5]:  {1: 123,
          2: 456,
          3: 579,
          4: ['', '0x7b', '0x1c8', 'Out[1] + Out[2]', 'In', 'Out']}
```

Comment: I want to believe this, but it doesn't match what I'm seeing. -- Can you explain why it randomly jumps? -- I executed a cell that contained one line of code and it went from 12 to 21.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking it is the total number of times you have runned the cells and that number on a particular cell in "In[num]" is the number at which you runned that cell latest.
hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).